# sIFR3 - diagonal text?

Tags: text, sifr3

I'm wondering if it's possible to create diagonal text with sIFR3 ?
I searched the net, but haven't come up with any leads so far.
Any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, a colleague has just sown me that this is indeed possible.
Just tilt the flash!!
Simples.